# What's a good background for a treasure hunter?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, background

I'm making a character for my friend's campaign.  I want to make him a treasure hunter.  I was looking at the backgrounds to see which one would be good for a profession like that, but I didn't see any.

What character background most closely fits *treasure hunter*?

Comment: Perrin, this question would be better if you laid out some criteria on what you feel constitutes "treasure hunter" as a background or a profession.  [It can be argued that any Rogue is by definition a treasure hunter, regardless of background](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/96625/22566).  Please narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: That's why I'm asking which background would suit that best, not class. I got my answer though.

Comment: Perrin, my point is that with the rogue class, any background can fit.  Glad that the answer got you what you wanted.

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean.

Comment: Many backgrounds fit it though. A Sage could be studying lost treasures. A Sailor could be a pirate (which is a treasure hunter by default). And that's 1 minute of thought from backgrounds I have in mind. If you don't define it better, any answer is as good as any other answer, which makes the question opinion-based. Good that you got the answer you expected nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the closest you'll get are the *Archaeologist* and *Anthropologist* from *Tomb of Annihilation*.

An *Archaeologist* learns about ancient cultures by studying their remains, ruins, masterworks, and tombs. That could easily be re-flavoured as a treasure hunter if you wanted.

The *Anthropologist* is a bit of of a stretch, focusing more on a particular culture's customs, but you could make it work.